# UnsatisfiedLinkError Java with Rxtx library

Tags: java, eclipse, arduino, rxtx

I am trying to communicate to Arduino with Java, so I'm using the rxtx library. I've downloaded the library and placed the respective files in my java project's folder. I put the rxtxxjar in a lib folder in the java project's folder, and I left the serial.jnlib straight into the java project's folder. I've taken the SerialTest code off of the arduino website, and I've tried to run it but I keep getting the UnsatisfiedLinkError. I've researched this question, and I've seen people saying basically the following in different ways:

> Go to Project -> properties -> Java build path ->Find your .jar. Click
>   on + to open the JAR's properties. Select Native library location and
>   edit it to point to RXTX's shared library (.DLL, .so, .dylib).

However, I have no idea how to do the pointing to the shared library, especially since I don't see any .dll, .so, or .dylib file, and I cannot use the .jnlib because it is greyed out. Also on a smaller note, by my .jar is that just the project? I work in Eclipse Java EE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
 System.load("Absolute path to your jni library");
```

This works fine on my project.